# Why is the Python 3.8 shell not executing parts of the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried executing this code from a Python 3.x book but the Python 3.8 shell will only execute the first two lines of code. If I remove the second line of code it will execute the code that is still there just fine for some reason. Is this a bug or is there something wrong with the code? I have tried restarting the shell and executing the code from a new file but nothing seems to be helping.

```
print("hello")
firstname=input("what is your first name? ")
print("thanks.")
surname=input("and what is your surname? ")
```

Comment: Are you providing the input it's asking for? Type something and hit enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine for me. You have to fill out the first input form before the second one will become available. And make sure you are hitting enter after you enter the text.